# Saving Google Places to 'My Maps' on mobile

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Essentially I want to save places to a 'My Maps' from a mobile web page.

- User accesses mobile site
- user searches Google places
- user is returned matches
- user saves relevant match to a 'My Maps'

This is standard functionality for desktop, however, this is not seen on the Google Maps iOS app or the mobile Google Maps site (and there is no Google My Places API I know of) which leads me to believe this is not possible on mobile. Is this the case?